# Actualizar el resultado de una funcio que devuelve un diccionario, agregandole los valores de un nuevo diccionario

Tags: python, funciones, diccionarios

hice un pequeño codigo que simula la creación de un inventario en forma de diccionario, cuando la función termina, me muestra los objetos agregados en el diccionario, ahora lo que tengo que hacer es crear una función donde al eliminar un enemigo me de su loot, actualizando el diccionario anterior pero no se como. esto es lo que tengo.

def Game_inventory():

```
print('Let´s start with your inventory')
inventory = {}

while True:

    object_inventory = input('Insert an object to add: ').capitalize()
    how_many = int(input(f'How many {object_inventory} are you taking? (Must be in range 5 - 12): '))

    if how_many in range(4, 13):
        print('Perfect, thats a good choice')
        inventory.setdefault(object_inventory, how_many)

    else:
        print('Must be in range (5,12)')
        print('Lets try again')
        how_many = int(input(f'How many {object_inventory} are you taking? (Must be in range 5 - 12): '))

        if how_many in range(4,13):
            inventory.setdefault(object_inventory, how_many)

    keep_adding = input('Something else? (Y OR N): ').capitalize()

    if keep_adding == 'Y':
        continue

    elif keep_adding == 'N':
        break

print('Your inventory is built in the following way')
print()

for key, value in inventory.items():
    print(key, '\t', value)

print('Thanks, lets go to the battle')
return inventory
```

def Loot_dragon():

```
dragon_items = {
    'Gold': 44,
    'Sword': 1
}

return first_try.update(dragon_items)
```

Disculpen si no se ve bien o no está bien optimizado, estoy recién aprendiendo. Buenas noches.

Comment: para dar el loot no deberias solo mostrar lo que hay en el inventario?, y vaciar el inventario del enemigo?

Comment: Es que lo que quiero es que lo que suelta mi enemigo se agregue a mi inventario